# CUDA 4.1 printf() Error

Tags: cuda

Even though I have a fermi card(gtx 560) I get this error on VS2010:

```
error : calling a host function("printf") from a __device__/__global__ function("kernel") is not allowed
```

Code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel()
{
  printf("hello");
}

int main()
{
  kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
  return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make sure you are compiling for the correct architecture. Only Fermi and Kepler cards (so compute capability 2.0, 2.1, 3.0 and 3.5 devices) support `printf` in kernels. If you compile your code like this:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_21 [other options] .....
```

the code should build correctly. The default architecture is compute 1.0, which is why you are getting the error. If you use Visual studio, there should be a project option to select the target architecture, although I can't tell you precisely where to find that as I don't use it with CUDA.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In VS2010 I changed Project->{Project Name} Properties->CUDA C/C++ ->Device -> [Code Generation]: compute_10, sm_10 to compute_20, sm_20 and it worked.

Comment: For your card, you should probably use sm_21, but I don't know whether it makes much difference to the code emitted by the compiler.