# CUDA 5.5 : I can't use "printf" at kernel method and which device should I select at VisualStucio2010 "compute_xx,sm_xx"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

this is the propaty by the deviceQuery.exe

```
Device 0: "NVS 4200M"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
( 1) Multiprocessors, ( 48) CUDA Cores/MP:     48 CUDA Cores
```

and which device should I select at VisualStucio2010 ?

compute_10,sm_10 or
compute_20,sm_20 or
compute_30,sm_30 or
compute_35,sm_35  ???

and I want to use printf at kernel method. 
but I couldn't use printf();
how to use printf at kernel side ?

what means the "compute_xx" ? sm equals streaming multiprocessors, isn't it?
I read the article below, but they did not know. 
[CUDA 4.1 printf() Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749652/cuda-4-1-printf-error)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `compute_20,sm_20` with that device.
If you select `compute_20,sm_20` you will be able to use `printf` [in the kernel](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output).

compute_20 selects a particular "virtual architecture"
sm_20 selects a particular "device architecture"

Both pieces of information are used by `nvcc`, the device code compiler, to generate code.

You can read more about the usage of these architecture specifiers by the compiler in the [nvcc manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architectures)

Comment: Thank you Robert Crovella! and I was able to run When you are as you say. Thank you!     but, How do you have identified the value that the compute_xx and sm_xx. I thought the sm_xx means the values of "streaming multiprocessors" . and the deviceQuery.exe's result show "( 1) Multiprocessors, ( 48) CUDA Cores/MP" it say Multiprocessors is 1 and I thought that I can use only sm_01.I want you to tell us about the value of compute_xx.
Where on the execution result of "deviceQuerry.exe" , can I identify the value?

Comment: Both compute_xx and sm_xx are chosen based on the *compute capability* (2.1) reported by device query